# How to add Places Autocomplete box inside a Google Maps InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am using the Google Maps Javascript API v3, and I am trying to insert a Places Autcomplete box inside an InfoWindow that appears when the user clicks on a marker.

I know how to create an autocomplete object, and I know how to create an info window that takes in just text input, but I don't know how to put my autocomplete object inside my infowindow.

This is what I have tried, among other things, but in this case the place where I want the auto complete box to be just says "Get directions from:
[object Object]". This is inside the InfoWindow.

Address is the address of my marker, which is working fine.

Here is my code snippet:

```
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete();
    var infoWindowContent = [
      '<div id="directions-to-here"> Get directions from:',
      autocomplete,
      '<p> to: </p>' + address
    ].join('<br>');

    var infoWindowOptions = {
      content: infoWindowContent,
      position: position
    }
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(toHereWindowOptions);
    infoWindow.open(map);
```

I also tried solving the problem by creating the autocomplete object after setting the info window content, with no luck:

```
var infoWindowContent = [
  '<div id="directions-to-here"> Get directions from:',
  '<input id="autocomplete" class="controls" type="text" 
  placeholder="Enter a starting location">',
  '<p> to: </p>' + address
].join('<br>');

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
   /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (
   document.getElementById('autocomplete')));
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by placing a Places Search Box in the infowindow. Please see the places search box documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

First set the content string:

```
var contentString = '<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">';
```

Then inside the click listener for the marker which opens the infowindow:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
infowindow.open(map, marker);
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
});
```

I have modified Google's infowindow sample [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) to have a search box in the infowindow that will autocomplete addresses. Please see my JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dpx9o1mo/1/

Note I have redacted my API key for security. Please input your own to use this sample.

I hope this helps!